# Kafka consumer local batch queue memory leak

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, confluent-kafka-dotnet

My service works with a topic through 10 consumers. Unmanaged memory grows immediately after adding a new batch of messages to a cluster topic (picture 1). Memory continues to grow even after a long period of inactivity.

[image]

When I sent 500k messages to the topic and starting the service, I saw the following:

[image]

I determined that is due to the local queue of the consumer, when changing parameters:

*QueuedMinMessages* - Minimum number of messages per topic+partition librdkafka tries to maintain in the local consumer queue. (Default: 100000; My value: 100)

*QueuedMaxMessagesKbytes* - Maximum number of kilobytes of queued pre-fetched messages in the local consumer queue. If using the high-level consumer this setting applies to the single consumer queue, regardless of the number of partitions. When using the legacy simple consumer or when separate partition queues are used this setting applies per partition. This value may be overshot by fetch.message.max.bytes. This property has higher priority than queued.min.messages. (Default: 65536; My value: 30000)

After changing these parameters and restart service (500k messages remain in topic):
[image]

Reducing values of these parameters only increased the memory fill time, but did not solve the problem of leak. For some reason, the local kafka queue is not being cleared of processed messages.

Сonsumer code:

```
private async Task StartConsumer(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, string>(_consumerConfig)
                       .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => _logger.LogError($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                       .Build())
            {
                
                consumer.Subscribe(_topicName);
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    ConsumeResult<string, string> result = null;
                    try
                    {
                        result = consumer.Consume();
                        if (result == null) continue;
                        var message = result.Message.Value;
                            Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{message}' at '{result.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
                            if (message != null)
                            {
                                T deserializedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message);
                                if (deserializedMessage != null)
                                {
                                    var handler = await _managerFactory.CreateHandler(_topicName);
                                    await handler.HandleAsync(deserializedMessage, _topicName);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _logger.LogInformation("Processed empty message from Kafka");
                            }
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Processed message from Kafka");
                            consumer.Commit(result);
                    }
                    catch (OracleException ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "OracleException" + '\n' + ex.Message + '\n' + ex.InnerException);
                        ProcessFailureMessage(result.Message);
                    }
                    catch (ConsumeException ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "ConsumerException" + '\n' + ex.Message + '\n' + ex.InnerException);
                    }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception" + '\n' + ex.Message + '\n' + ex.InnerException);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Kafka connection error");
        }

    }
```

Consumer config:

```
"RequestTimeoutMs": 60000,
"TransactionTimeoutMs": 300000,
"SessionTimeoutMs": 300000,
"EnableAutoCommit": false,
"QueuedMinMessages": 100,
"QueuedMaxMessagesKbytes": 30000,
"AutoOffsetReset": "Earliest",
"AllowAutoCreateTopics": true,
"PartitionAssignmentStrategy": "RoundRobin"
```

confluent-kafka-dotnet version 1.9.3

UPD 1:
StartConsumer() calling like long running task:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _consumersCount; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartConsumer(stoppingToken),
            stoppingToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: I see StartConsumer is an async method, is calling trying to called multiple times per consumer? it should be called once per consumer.

Comment: He's started like long running task. Added information to the description.

Comment: _consumersCount shall be equal to number of partitions. Can you ensure the _consumersCount = topic's partitions?

Comment: Number of consumers and partitions is exactly same

Comment: Did you find the root cause? We're having the same issue when consuming large messages. While keeping the consumed messages rather  small there's no memory leak

Comment: Still no progress? I am facing the same issue rn.. memory leak is not as big when we have one common instance for all topics.. But we need to separe consumers per topics to not block others by handling

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library and see if the problem remains:
https://github.com/soucore/Reactive.Kafka.Client

Comment: Welcome at SO! Maybe you want to elaborate your answer? 
This may help the questioner to fully understand, if, and how your proposed solution can solve the problem reported. Furthermore, you would add know-how to the SO knowledge base.